# Angular Scope, separating arrays so they do not collide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use this really cool isteven-multi-select, and my problem occurred when I needed the same dropdown in two different places. The problem is that when I change one, the other also change and vice versa.

[image]

They have nothing to do with each other and have completely different variable names, field names etc.. the only thing they share is the place I set them up.

```
let tempList = [
    {
        flag: "payCard.png",
        code: "Credit Card"
    },
    {
        flag: "payBank.png",
        code: "Bank Transfer"
    },
    etc..
]
$scope.paymentList = tempList;
$scope.FooBaa      = tempList;
```

Even thou this templist is setup far away in a function long forgotten, they still insist on sharing it and duplicating each other.

**BUT!!!** if I do this, then it works......

```
let tempList = [
    {
        flag: "payCard.png",
        code: "Credit Card"
    },
    {
        flag: "payBank.png",
        code: "Bank Transfer"
    },
    etc..
]
$scope.paymentList = tempList;

let tempList2 = [
    {
        flag: "payCard.png",
        code: "Credit Card"
    },
    {
        flag: "payBank.png",
        code: "Bank Transfer"
    },
    etc..
]
$scope.FooBaa = tempList2;
```

Can someone explain why?  This is a total mystery for me, been cooking over it for 3 hours now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are reference types, so you are just pointing `FooBaa` to the same exact array in memory:

```
$scope.paymentList = tempList;
$scope.FooBaa      = tempList; // same exact array (not duplicated)
```

Maybe you'd like a copy:

```
$scope.paymentList = tempList;
$scope.FooBaa      = angular.copy(tempList);
```

Comment: Ohhhh Frank!!  I thought a "let" would be destroyed as soon as you left the function :)  - a copy is what I need!!   Thanks a lot, will try it at once.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard If the `let` were inside braces and the rest of the code were not, then you wouldn't have access to the variable. But that's really a different concept than reference/value types.

Comment: but this only goes for anything $scope related right?  I mean if you do a `myArray = [1,2,3,4]` and then do `yourArray = myArray` then any changes in yourArray will not be reflected in myArray. Correct?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard You'll have the same problem. If you mutate one array, the other variable will show the changes too, because they are both references to the same exact array. You may want to read up on the difference between value and reference types.